# Should I mention my doctor’s appointment at my meeting with HR?

Tags: united-states, human-resources, sickness

Recently, I was involved in an incident where an employee sprayed air from one of the compressed tanks we use for the soda machines at my face, resulting in my loss of hearing for three seconds following.

I reported the incident as soon as I was able to get one of my managers one-on-one, and while the incident has been reported and a punishment issued (no idea how much further it’ll go for the other person), I have had a sore throat and a rather nasty cough for the last three days. For context, this happened on a Saturday evening.

I have an appointment to see HR this afternoon and provide more details and sign off on their report, but I don’t know whether I should mention my doctor’s appointment as well.

I will be mentioning this incident to my doctor since I feel there is a possibility it is related to my current condition. However, I cannot come to a decision as to whether to inform HR. It seems like I should, but I do not want to cast suspicions or otherwise alter anyone’s perspectives without knowing for certain or with a great deal of certainty that this current ailment is related to this incident, especially since I will be seeing the doctor for another issue that has been present since before Saturday.

My question is simple: *Do I inform HR now or wait for the doctor’s conclusion to say anything?*

Comment: @JoeStrazzere My main thing is to avoid any future conflicts since the incident was entirely the other person's fault. Whether or not they are fired is not of immediate concern since this is the worst they've done besides be a major pain the butt socially. Besides, I would rather HR make that decision, not me. If I do end up sick to the point where I need to be off work, I would like to be compensated my pay since we don't do PTO, so that's kind of the only thing at this point.

Comment: You should also tell your doctor (front desk clerk) up-front that this might turn into a worker's compensation claim. There's special paperwork for that. The urgent care facility that I use has a checkbox on their form, for instance.

Comment: I cannot understand why compressed air would cause a sore throat or a bad cough.  Sounds like you have an infection?

Comment: @JonH, when air is compressed, it's usually also dried to prevent rust build-up in the tank.  When it expands again, it cools off dramatically; a compressed-air nozzle can cool to the point that ice forms on it even in the summer.  Your throat does not do well in extremely cold, dry air.

Comment: This is very specific to the OP's situation and doesn't seem generalized to anyone else. SE is about asking questions that will be of interest to other people, not just the OP.

Comment: @BenCrowell I mean yes, but there’s no existing record on this site of what to do if an illness/injury is suspected following a workplace accident or incident. What may be common knowledge to the average person may not be to younger or less experienced persons such as myself.

Comment: @BenCrowell Didn't we abolish the too localised close reason long ago?

Comment: Is there some kind of insurance regarding accidents on the job involved? If so, there might be requirements to inform the employee and send the doctors report to the insurance.

Answer (score 79):

> Do I inform HR now

### Yes.

At this point since HR is involved, be **open and honest** and tell them everything related to the incident.  If you're going to the doctor due to what happened, then yes you need to tell them.

I am not a fan of getting HR involved in anything unless you **have to**, but when you do, *be completely transparent* as it relates to the incident HR is involved in.  Lying or omitting anything will look very bad on you should it come out down the road.

Comment: Yep.  Let HR decide what is and isn't relevant to this situation.

Comment: If it does come out that my illness is related to this incident, what would my course of action be from there? (Might be better as a separate question but someone I know keeps mentioning that it’s a workman comp thing and I am COMPLETELY in the dark on that)

Comment: @Pleiades I would assume that you would be paid if you were unable to work due to the fact that you were injured on the job.  That being said, see what HR says, and if its not fair get a lawyer.  These laws differ state to state.  This will also depend on how long you need to recover.

Comment: You might want to seek some advise from a Union rep, as they often make sure the company isn't cutting any corners.

Comment: @Pleiades If it does turn out that your illness is related to the incident, and said illness is even moderately serious (rather than, "oh, you'll just have a sore throat for a few days"), I'd strongly recommend to talk to a lawyer (if you are a member of a union, they likely have lawyers on hand).  You might have a strong case for compensation.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, which I fully agree with, it will work out better for you if you mention the appointment and then later have to tell HR that it's just a common cold and unrelated than if you _don't_ mention the appointment and later find out that there _is_ a possibility that it's related. At the very least it should create something of a paper trail about the effects of the incident which you may later come to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Since your HR appointment is scheduled before the appointment with your doctor, I don't see how waiting for the doctor's conclusion is an option.

During your meeting with the HR you should mention your health issues, and that you're currently not certain whether these are related to the incident or to a condition you had since before Saturday. Tell them when your doctor's appointment is, and ask them if they will want any special forms filled by the doctor.

This will give the HR a clear deadline for gathering all the information, after which they will be able to decide how to proceed.

Comment: Don't mention a possible previous condition. Let the doctor figure that out.